# variant ="outlined" input doesn't set label label gap correctly

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui

there is no gap when I set to select variant="outlined"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZJcx.png)

there is a component:

```
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined">
          <InputLabel id="currencies-select">
            <FormattedMessage id="select.currency" defaultMessage="currency" />
          </InputLabel>
          <SelectContent
            name="currencies-select"
            labelid="currencies-select"
            multiple={false}
            content={content}
            contentValue="name"
            handleValueFunc={this.handleCurrency}
            label={<FormattedMessage id="select.currency" defaultMessage="currency" />}
          />
        </FormControl>
      </Fragment>
    );
```

and there is a main component:

```
    <Fragment>
      <Select
        multiple={multiple}
        value={selValue}
        onChange={handleValueFunc}
        inputProps={{ name: `${name}`, id: `${name}`, readOnly }}
      >
        {allValue && (
          <MenuItem value={-1}>
            <FormattedMessage id="select.all" defaultMessage="All" />
          </MenuItem>
        )}
        {content.map(item => (
          <MenuItem key={item.id} value={Number(item.id)}>
            {item[contentValue]}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </Fragment>
```

displayed like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZJcx.png)
Where did I make a mistake? I've already tried everything